# Temporarily moving a SQL Server 2016 database to SQL Server 2017 and then moving back. Is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, restore, sql-server-2017

If I take a backup of a database from a SQL Server 2016 instance and then restore it to a 2017 instance to do some work on it.

Can I then turn around and back up that database from the 2017 instance and use that to overwrite the original version on the 2016 instance?

Comment: See also [SQL Server database backup restore on lower version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6183139/18192).  It is possible to migrate a database to a lower version of SQL (assuming compatible schemas), but not via native backup/restore.  Other options include BCP, script generation, third party tools, bacpac, etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, this is not possible.SQL Server 2017 backups cannot be restored by any earlier version of SQL Server [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/copy-databases-with-backup-and-restore?view=sql-server-2017)

Also, regarding detatching and reattaching [per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/upgrade-a-database-using-detach-and-attach-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> After being attached to SQL Server 2017, the database is available
>   immediately and is automatically upgraded. This prevents the database
>   from being used with an older version of the Database Engine

Also, not sure you care about the compatibility level, but FYSA:

> If the compatibility level of a user database is 100 or higher before
>   upgrade, it remains the same after upgrade. If the compatibility level
>   is 90 before upgrade in the upgraded database, the compatibility level
>   is set to 100, which is the lowest supported compatibility level in
>   SQL Server 2017.

Additionally, I believe you question is about a user database, [but if it isn't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/copy-databases-with-backup-and-restore?view=sql-server-2017):

> Backups of master, model and msdb that were created by using an
>   earlier version of SQL Server cannot be restored by SQL Server 2017